# How to compare in C#

Tags: c#

I have two strings.

```
                string a="50";
                string b="60";
```

Now I want to comapre the value of string a and b with respect to their values, i.e. here b>a..
What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to convert them to integers to be able to compare them numerically, so:

```
string a = "50";
string b = "60";
bool isBGreaterThanA = Convert.ToInt32(b) > Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

Comment: should i go 4 convert or tryparse

Comment: @Wondering: That depends on whether you want an exception to be thrown if the strings aren't really integers.

Comment: @Wondering: If your data has been validated, no need to use `TryParse`.

Comment: @Wondering, that depends on if you're *sure* the values will always be integers, or not. If you're 100% sure they will be and thus any time they won't is truly *exceptional*, then go for a Convert.ToInt32, otherwise use int.TryParse =)

Comment: +1. You can also use ''Int32.Parse()'' instead of ''Convert.ToInt32''.

Comment: Exactly, minding that 'Convert.ToInt32' calls a 'int32.Parse', plus a null check. If you are sure, just go with the parse.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a small example to compare the values of two strings. If they can be converted to numbers, then it will compare their numeric value. Otherwise it will compare them alphabetically.

```
private bool GreaterThan(string firstString, string secondString)
{
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    if (int.TryParse(firstString, out firstNumber) && int.TryParse(secondString, out secondNumber))
    {
        return firstNumber > secondNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        // Greater than 0 means the instance follows the value
        return firstString.CompareTo(secondString) > 0;
    }
}
```

You could also implement this as a String extension method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert both the string to integer and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert them to Integers before comparing. But why have numbers as strings?

Comment: One example I can think of is asp.net's Request.QueryString[] collection, anything passed around that way gets returned as a string. Oh, and the "newbies curse" of treating everything as a string, I guess ;)

Comment: actually this is coming as string, I cant change it to Int :-), similar to the query string situation

Answer (score -3):

Misunderstood the question and suggested the string.Compare and was wrong.

How about write a small extension to your string so that you can always ask for Int value of it saving you to parse or convert it over and over again at various place of your code'

```
public static class stringExtensions
{
    public static int IntValue(this string s)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out res))
            return res;
        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this

```
Console.WriteLine (b.IntValue() > a.IntValue()? "b > a" : "a >= b");
```